# Why can't I see a list of all my communities in the profile area?

Tags: support, profile-page, hidden-communities

In my Stack Overflow profile there is a window on the left that shows some of the other communities I'm active on. When I click 'edit', a new menu appears that contains an option called 'hide communities'. When I click it, a list with communities is loaded and I'm able to hide communities from the list that is displayed on my profile page.

Above the list it says

> Showing 12 community out of 31 visible communities

Why am I only able to hide 12 of the 31 communities and why can't I see all 31 of them on my profile page?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why it's showing only 12 communit**ies** (it's showing 12 for me too) (maybe some pagination component should be there but is missing?) - anyway, as a workaround, you can type the name of the site you want to hide in the "Search sites" field and then click "Add to hidden communities".

Comment: I have 170 communities. I see 12. If I want to hide the 158 other communities I have to search for them first so they show up in the list. Hold my beer, I'm editing my communities ....

Comment: On that same page *New sites that you join will be linked to your other communities by default.* What *other* communities? I assume *visible* was meant there.

Comment: i guess this is probably some bug then

Comment: I think this is by design. The UX team considers users with more then 12 communities outliers that you don't need to offer easy use of the feature.

Answer (score 5):

The exact reason for this limit is unknown: there are no public explanations, and the list of communities is loaded via server-side rendering, so the source code documentation cannot help us here either. There is also an old feature request requesting for the limit to be lifted with no official acknowledgment thus far:

[Can we please have the full list shown in Hide Communities?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271743/786798)

Give it [6 to 8](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/786798) to be noticed. In the meantime, I [made a userscript](https://stackapps.com/q/9304/78873) that loads every visible community the user is a part of in a nice list (as well as reduces row padding to make better use of the available viewport space). Note that it requires a userscript manager ([Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)) due to the [lack of CORS headers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212774/786798) sent in response to requesting non-API pages of the network.

Answer (score 4):

In case you just want to see all your communities, you can click on this link:

https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=accounts

You can manually navigate to it by clicking on the icon in the top right and clicking "YOUR COMMUNITIES".

[image]